# localStorage accessible only after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, sencha-touch-2, web-storage

I am developping a mobile web application using **Sencha Touch 2.0.0.RC** but I don't think my problem is related to this framework.

Here is the workflow :

At startup, **app.js** is loaded and checks if a token exists in local storage :

```js
launch: function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('myToken')) {
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.Viewport');
    }
    else{
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.Login');
    }
}
```

Because I load the application for the first time, no token is found so login view is created.

In the **login.js** controller, **submitLoginForm** function gets form values and sends an ajax request to a rest API :

```js
submitLoginForm: function () {
    var formValues = this.getLoginForm().getValues();

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        scope: this,
        url: 'http://mydomain.com/api/login/token',
        method: 'POST',
        params: formValues,
        success: function (response) {
            var result = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            if (result.success) {
                localStorage.setItem('myToken', result.token);
                var viewport = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Viewport');
                this.getLoginForm().setHidden(true);
                viewport.show();
            }
            else{
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Bad username or password');
            }
        },
        failure: function () {
            // 
        }
    });
}
```

When username and password are correct, a token is returned which I store in localStorage.
After that, I create and show another view (**viewport.js**) which makes use of the token to access the API :

```js
store: {
    //...
    proxy: {
        //...
        url: 'http://mydomain.com/api/controller/function/?token=' + localStorage.getItem('myToken')
    }
}
```

At that moment the url looks like this :

```
http://mydomain.com/api/controller/function/?token=null&...
```

But when I refresh my browser, everything is fine and the token is back :

```
http://mydomain.com/api/controller/function/?token=tokenValue&...
```

I can also completely close my browser, open it again and access my whole application without being asked for login.

Comment: While S.O. is nice, also try posting at [ST2.X Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?90-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Q-amp-A). There is a dude named `mitchellsimoens` which knows alot of sencha (he's moderator) and normally answer fast.

Comment: Yeah I know that guy, he's very active. I have now posted my question in that forum. I was thinking I would have better luck here because (in my opinion) this has nothing to do with Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to my misunderstanding of Sencha Touch. I was creating a store in the config which is called before all I described. mitchellsimoens was indeed the right person, he did answered fast and understood by himself that I was creating my store in the config of my view... http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185690-localStorage-accessible-only-after-refresh

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the built-in localstorage proxy?

See http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-proxy

Then just set the proxy like this:

```
proxy: {
  id: 'myproxy',
  type: 'localstorage'
}
```

Then query your store for the data.

Comment: Why should I use this proxy which means several lines of code and an additional file with a model definition that has a unique field when a single line does the job?